# What does "limits" mean under the node allocated resources?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to understand output of the command:

```
oc describe no master01 | grep 0iA5 allocated
```

In the attached image, I understand that `cpu/memory requests represent` the amount of `cpu and memory` that the container is `guaranteed` to have `on this particular node.`

However, what it means to have a CPU limit of `980m` on the node?

Also, my understanding is that limit value is always greater than equal to requests value. So, how come limits is showing a value lower than requests?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it means millicores (one-onethousandth of a full cpu core).

Comment: and all pods have probably not specified a _limit_, so the sum of it is low.

Comment: if you remove the grep part, I think you see the numbers for each pod, and it is easy to see why there is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of the `kubectl describe node` output describes the resource constraints of the Pods that have been scheduled on the Node.  So for example, the "memory" line doesn't say that the Node has 13 GB of RAM, but rather that the Pods scheduled on the Node combined have requested 13 GB of RAM, which is 66% of what's available on the system.

A Pod doesn't necessarily have to declare a resource limit.  I'm guessing that's what you're seeing here: most of the Pods that are scheduled have some non-trivial resource request but no declared limit.

If every Pod *does* declare resource limits, then this gives you some idea of how overcommitted the Node is: if every Pod ran at its maximum resource limits, how many Nodes would you actually need to run the workload?  If some of the Pods don't, though, the "total limits" column isn't necessarily that meaningful.